# UseEffect not recognizing new value from useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a useEffect that has a value based off a useSelector. When I delete an item from redux, the useSelector is running (I get the value in the console.log) and I am getting the updated restaurantToTry list. The useeffect though is not getting triggered when I delete an item. The only time it gets triggered is when I go from 1 to 0 items in the array.

```
const restaurantsToTry = useSelector(fetchRestaurantsBookmarked);
console.log("restaurantsToTry, ", restaurantsToTry);
const [filteredRestaurants, setFilteredRestaurants] =
    React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("it should come he re ");
    setFilteredRestaurants(restaurantsToTry);
}, [restaurantsToTry]);
```

Comment: use restaurantsToTry.length in useEffect dependencies

Comment: If I use restaurantsToTry.length then it won't run when there's an update to an existing entry. Regardless though, I tried using restaurants.length as a dependency and it still doesn't run. I have a console.log statement in my useeffect to confirm that it's not running

Comment: Instead of posting screen shot of code please add code itself, so we can update the code as need

Comment: Sorry, updated!